# Is there a reason that not the whole string is printed?

Tags: c++

**I'm writing a program that reads each line from a text file and stores each word in a vector.
I noticed when running the program that not the whole initial text is printed. Any idea why?**

This is the file:

> It was a Thursday, but it felt like a Monday to John. And John loved
> Mondays. He thrived at work. He dismissed the old cliché of dreading
> Monday mornings and refused to engage in water-cooler complaints about
> “the grind” and empty conversations that included the familiar parry
> “How was your weekend?” “Too short!”. Yes, John liked his work and was
> unashamed.
>
> I should probably get another latte. I’ve just been sitting here with
> this empty cup. But then I’ll start to get jittery. I’ll get a decaf.
> No, that’s stupid, it feels stupid to pay for a decaf. I can’t justify
> that.
>
> John was always impatient on the weekends; he missed the formal
> structure of the business week. When he was younger he used to stay
> late after school on Fridays and come in early on Mondays, a pattern
> his mother referred to with equal parts admiration and disdain as
> “studying overtime.”
>
> Jesus, I’ve written another loser.
>
> Now, John spent his weekends doing yard work at the Tudor house
> Rebecca left him after their divorce. Rebecca, with her almond
> eyes—both in shape and in color—could never be his enemy.
>
> That barista keeps looking at me. She’ll probably ask me to leave if I
> don’t buy something. She’s kind of attractive. Not her hair—her hair
> seems stringy—but her face is nice. I should really buy something.
>
> Their divorce was remarkably amicable. In fact, John would often tell
> his parents, “Rebecca and I are better friends now than when we were
> married!” In fact, John looked forward to the days when he and
> Rebecca, with their new partners, would reminisce about their
> marriage, seeing it in a positive light, like two mature adults.
>
> Maybe I’ll just get a pumpkin-spice loaf. That way I can still sit
> here without going through a whole production of buying a coffee and
> giving my name and feeling like an asshole while it gets made.

And the code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>


std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& s, char delim = ' ');

int main()
{   
    std::cout << "File name: ";
    std::string fname;
    std::cin >> fname;

    std::ifstream inpob {fname, std::ios_base::in};

    if (!inpob.is_open()) std::cout << "Error opening file " << fname;
    else
    {
        std::string str = "";
    
        for (std::string line; std::getline(inpob, line);)
            str += line;
    
    
        std::vector<std::string> splited = split(str);
    
        for (std::string word : splited) std::cout << word;
    
        std::cout << "\nWords: " << splited.size() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}


std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& str, char delim)
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;

    std::string word = "";

    for (char c : str)
    {
        if (c == delim)
        {
            word += delim;
            v.push_back(word);
            word = "";
            continue;
        }
        word += c;
    }

    return v;
}
```

Comment: add some [std::endl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) in your code. Compile it with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your program

Comment: ok i'll try that out, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the final word to the vector.

```
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& str, char delim)
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;

    std::string word = "";

    for (char c : str)
    {
        if (c == delim)
        {
            word += delim;
            v.push_back(word);
            word = "";
            continue;
        }
        word += c;
    }

    if (word != "") v.push_back(word); // add this
    return v;
}
```

Comment: This code can be greatly simplified if you use `std::istringstream` and `std::getline()` to read delimited words, eg: `std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& str, char delim) { vector<std::string> v; std::istringstream iss(str); std::string word; while (std::getline(iss, word, delim) { v.push_back(word); } return v; }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Your code is not equivalent with this `split`. Your code won't add delimiter for each words. Your code won't put empty (or delimiter-only) words when there are continuous multiple delimiters.